# ASP.NET Core accessing user account from admin account

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on ASP.NET Core application which has two types of user roles, `admin` and `user`.`user` has its own dashboard and other pages and `admin` also has its own dashboard and other pages. Both user sign in through same sign in page and redirected to same domain say `abc.com`. Now `admin` wants to change settings in user accounts by accessing `abc.com/User/{userName}`(only accessible to admins). When admin visits  `abc.com/User/{userName}`, I want to show whole user dashboard and settings like normal `user` would see after signing in to account based on `userName` parameter. If I come back to `abc.com` then it will show admin account and if I go to `abc.com/User/{userName}` it will show me that particular user account. How do I achieve this? I want to avoid writing extra code to edit user account details from admin side.It will be easier to access user account and change settings there. Both `admin` and `user` have same layout page and same controller called `UserController`.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple

```
if(User.HasClaim(yourAdminClaim))
{
//do admin stuff and pass to view
}
else
{
//do user stuff and pass to view
}
```

Comment: Admin wants to login to user account by accessing abc.com/user/{username} without signing out from its own admin account. Sign in through this link should be same as normal sign in.